# What does tcp_disconnect function in the Linux kernel do, and under what circumstances is it invoked?

Tags: c, linux, tcp, kernel

I am trying to implement a ULP in a Linux kernel module, and have been looking at the function pointers in the global variable `struct proto tcp_prot`, so that I can get a feel of which function pointer fields to copy into my own `struct proto` and which fields to override with my own implementation. One of the fields of `struct proto` is `disconnect`, which is set to the kernel function `tcp_disconnect`. However, I can't seem to find a user-space analogue of this function, and Google is not yielding anything useful. So what's the purpose of `tcp_disconnect`? What does it do and when is it invoked?

Answer (score 0):

Like most protocol stacks the TCP/IP stack in the linux kernel is implemented as a *state machine*, this is i.e. in https://wiki.aalto.fi/download/attachments/70789052/linux-tcp-review.pdf on page 5. So the TCP protocol  is not fully exported to user space, instead there is 'hidden communication' between the machines.

The source code for `tcp_disconnect()` in the TCP state machine in the linux kernel is in https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.6/source/net/ipv4/tcp.c#L2191

http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_TCPOperationalOverviewandtheTCPFiniteStateMachineF-2.htm